# Filling attribute tables with values from the same attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, if-else

Just wondering  if there's an easy way to fill null values in one column in an attribute table with values in another column of the same attribute table by just writing a query "just the "null values" to be filled with details I already have in another column".Found this query
 field 1= sec volt, field 2: Lv connection

```
def updateValue( !SecVolt!, !LVConnection! ): 
if !SecVolt! is None: return !LVConnection! 
else: return '0'
```

but in my case I don't want to replace the value with "0" but with values in another column.

Comment: Yes I can use field calculator but the query seem not to be working!

Answer (score 4):

All geoprocessing tools honour selections. So simply select the rows where column 1 has the NULL values then run a field calculate and select the field you want the values to come from. As you have a selection only those rows will be updated. Absolutely no code required.

Comment: +1 because this applies to scores of similar questions. Minimize use of coding is also right, too much bias lately.

Answer (score 2):

With python parser try:

Code block:

```
def updateValue(field1, field2):
    if field1 is None:
        return field2
    else:
        return '0'
```

Call with:

realfieldname1=

```
updateValue(!realfieldname1!,!realfieldname2!)
```

When you call the function you must use the real fieldname enclosed in !!

Comment: Tried doing it this way still didn't work. here is what i tried: field 1= sec volt, field 2: Lv connection <def updateValue( !SecVolt!, !LVConnection! ): if !SecVolt! is None: return !LVConnection! else: return '0'>

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you try with. Are you sure the field you are calculating is string/text type? Otherwise `return '0'` should be `return 0`

Comment: Thanks for your response, that might be the issue why i'm getting error response. one is a "string type" and one is a "long type" and the other table was brought in through a join relationship....so I'm trying to just bring it in without any join relationship to see if it works.